# Webpack4 codesplitting duplicate Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-4, code-splitting

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    vendors: "./src/vendor",
    main: "./src/index.js",
    auth: "./src/auth.js",
    search: "./src/search.js",
    cinema: "./src/cinema.js"
  },
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          chunks: "all"
        }
      },
    },
    runtimeChunk: "single",
  }
```

This is working good. But the chunks for cinema.js and main.js have duplicate entries. Please help me on how to avoid it.
I need to move duplicate code from cinema.js to main.js